# Why does trying to access an attribute in LINQ-to-XML give me an error?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

According to my LINQ book, this slightly altered example should work.

Why does it tell me "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**"?

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TestNoAttribute
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("employee",
                    new XAttribute("id", "23"),
                    new XElement("firstName", new XAttribute("display", "true"), "Jim"),
                    new XElement("lastName", new XAttribute("display", "false"), "Smith")));

            XElement element = xdoc.Element("firstName");
            XAttribute attribute = element.Attribute("display"); //error

            Console.WriteLine(xdoc);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

## Partial Answer:

I figured out if I change **XDocument** to **XElement**, then it works. Could anyone explain **why**?

Comment: Could you post your XML document, as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing a child element of `xdoc` that doesn't exist. Try one level down:

```
XElement element = xdoc.Element("employee").Element("firstName");
```

or

```
XElement element = xdoc.Descendants("firstName").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Agreed, but why does it throw the exception on the next line of code, rather than this one?

Comment: Because in the next line of code element was null. If the element doesn't exist no exception is thrown (at xdoc.Element("firstName")).

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) on MSDN as to why.  It explicitly explains their 'idiom' on why they felt returning a null element when the name is not found was beneficial.